# How to convert from string to int/float in C++17 with std:from_chars

Tags: c++, string, c++17

What are good examples for usage of [std::from_chars](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) (C++17)

- to convert from sequence of characters to int
- to convert from sequence of characters to float

?

[Open-Std std::from_chars](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0067r5.html)

Comment: This looks like a broad question. However, the linked paper gives a rather thorough description including rationale. So, this question really should be 3 individual questions: one about examples (but highlighting what's missing from the rationale), one about rounding, and one about return values.

Comment: Ok, deleted question about rounding and question about return values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what exactly you want to do, which is important for knowing how you want to handle the return value.

If you want to handle the different possible error types differently, you would compare the `ec` member of the `std::from_chars_result` to the values `std::errc::invalid_argument` or `std::errc::out_of_range`. If you only care about success/failure, you would cast it to `bool` instead (according to [P0067R5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0067r5.html), in the case of success the value of `ec` will be `false` when cast to `bool`). If you care about the entire string being parsed, then you will also need to check the `ptr` member as well.

For example, the below function will parse the C string to a `std::optional<int>`, with the value being empty if an error occurs or if the entire string was not parsed (e.g. if you try to parse something like "123.45")

```
auto tryParseInt(const char* src)->std::optional<int>
{
    const char* end = std::strchr(src, 0); // find the terminating null

    int parsed;
    std::from_chars_result result = std::from_chars(src, end, parsed);

    return (!(bool)result.ec && result.ptr == end)
        ? std::optional<int>{ parsed }
        : std::nullopt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a simple example using the `int` variant:

```
char input[] = "foo 123 bar";

int value;
auto result = std::from_chars(input + 4, input + 6, value);  // input[4] to input[6] should be a three-digit integer
if (result.ec == std::errc::invalid_argument)
{
    std::cout << "Unsuccessful parse\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Successful parse, value is " << value << '\n';
}
```

It's important to note that since `value` is not initialized by me, and on failure it will be left unmodified, it can only be used if the parsing of the string-segment was successful.

Comment: Thank you. What about checking for std::errc::result_out_of_range as well?

Comment: @ToBe Just add an `else if (...)` check for it? Or include in the condition with logical or `||` of the `if`?

Comment: Sorry, I am not asking about how to implement an additional check. I wondered about your example where you let the case of result_out_of_range run into the "successful" part.

Comment: @ToBe Well it's an *simple (and incomplete) example*, I didn't really care about it being complete. Instead I hope the readers are smart enough to add additional error checking themselves.